# How to manage the cumulative time callout limit?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, callout

i searched aroud a solution, but I didn't found someone that already made the question.

I'm searching an approach to calculate the value of the cumulative time spent in callouts... I checked the apex limits class, but there wasn't no method to use for this limit.

There is any smart solution to know the actual time spent i callouts?

I would use this approach to avoid to make useless callouts and start processes in other systems when I know that I'm not able to wait for the answere.

thnks,
K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's interesting. I myself thought there was some method for that, but it appears that Limits doesn't have such a method.

You could always use an approximation by measuring the time in milliseconds by using:

```
Long startTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
HttpResponse res = binding.send(req);
Long stopTime = DateTime.now().getTime();

timeUsed += stopTime-startTime;
```

This should be accurate within a handful of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

There's an apex class that's part of the [Apex-Lang Utils Library](http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/) called `StopWatch.cls` that should provide the functionality that you're looking for. It has methods for getting the time of running states, their time splits and various other time methods. The utilities are also available on Git someplace, but the Google link was the quickest one I could find at hand.